# Delegate attribute methods to the parent object

Tags: ruby, delegation

I have the following class:

```
class Alphabet

  attr_reader :letter_freqs, :statistic_letter

  def initialize(lang)
    @lang = lang
    case lang
    when :en
      @alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
      @letter_freqs = { ... }
    when :ru
      @alphabet = ('А'..'Я').to_a.insert(6, 'Ё')
      @letter_freqs = { ... }
    ...
    end
    @statistic_letter = @letter_freqs.max_by { |k, v| v }[0]
  end

end

foo = Alphabet.new(:en)
```

The central member here is `@alphabet`.

I'd like to make it some sort of a container class to invoke Array methods directly like

```
foo[i]
foo.include?
```

instead of explicitly accessing `@alphabet`:

```
foo.alphabet[i]
foo.alphabet.include?
```

I know I could define a lot of methods like

```
def [](i)
  @alphabet[i]
end
```

but I'm looking for a proper way of "inheriting" them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Forwardable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) (it is included in the Ruby standard library):

```
require 'forwardable'

class Alphabet

  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@alphabet, :[], :include?

  def initialize
    @alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  end

end

foo = Alphabet.new

p foo[0]           #=> "A"
p foo.include? 'ç' #=> false
```

If you wish to delegate all the methods not defined by your class you can use [`SimpleDelegator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) (also in the standard library); it lets you delegate all the methods that are not responded by the instance to an object specified by `__setobj__`:

```
require 'delegate'

class Alphabet < SimpleDelegator

  def initialize
    @alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
    __setobj__(@alphabet)
  end

  def index
    'This is not @alphabet.index'
  end

end

foo = Alphabet.new

p foo[0]           #=> "A"
p foo.include? 'ç' #=> false
p foo.index        #=> "This is not @alphabet.index"
```

When the delegate doesn't need to be dynamic you can arrange the master class to be a subclass of `DelegateClass`, passing the name of the class to be delegated as argument and calling `super` passing the object to be delegated in the `#initialize` method of the master class:

```
class Alphabet < DelegateClass(Array)

  def initialize
    @alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
    super(@alphabet)
  end
```

More info about the delegation design pattern in Ruby [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_patterns.html)

Comment: Wow that's nice :) Any chance I can delegate ALL methods? or maybe that's not a good idea?

Comment: Don't delegate all methods since they probably share some of the same method names such as `class`,, which would probably make chaos.

Comment: @Zippie, accepting this answer because it has info on delegating all methods. Thanks for your warning, though :)

Comment: No problem, this is the better answer

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the [Forwardable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module:

```
class Alphabet
  require 'forwardable'
  extend Forwardable
  attr_accessor :alphabet

  def initialize
    @alphabet = [1,2,3]
  end


  def_delegator :@alphabet, :[], :include?
end
```

Then you can do:

```
alpha = Alphabet.new
alpha[1]==hey.alphabet[1]
=> true
```

**Warning:**

Don't try to delegate all methods (don't know if that's even possible) since they probably share some of the same method names such as `class`, which would probably make chaos.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can extend Objects like this.

```
class Array
  def second
    self[1]
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].second
# => 2
```

Or if you want to inherit an Array.

```
class Foo < Array
  def second
    self[1]
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].include? 2
# => true

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].second
# => 2
```

If you have any further questions, comment and I will update the answer.